# Is every regular/context free langauge decidable in LogSpace?

Tags: regular-languages, terminology, decision-problem, space-complexity

I know all the regular languages are decidable but not sure whether it can be done in LogSpace.

Answer (score 3):

For regular languages, we have 
    $$ \text{REG = DSPACE}(O(1)) = \text{NSPACE}(O(1))$$
where REG is the class of regular languages. This can be easily seen from the equivalent formalisms of regular languages. A language is a regular language iff it is the language accepted by a deterministic finite automaton. A language is a regular language iff it is the language accepted by a nondeterministic finite automaton.

In fact, $\text{REG = DSPACE}(o(\log \log n))$. That is, $Ω(\log\log n)$ space is required to recognize any non-regular language [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE#Complexity_classes).

For context-free languages, please see the answer by Yuval Filmus.

Comment: Is it same for context free language?

Comment: No.  If a language can be decided using constant space, then we can use a deterministic finite automaton to recognize the strings in that language.

Answer (score 3):

It is unknown whether context-free languages can be decided in logarithmic space. The best known result shows that they can be decided in nondeterministic space $O(\log^2 n)$. It is also known that if all context-free languages can be decided in deterministic logarithmic space then $\mathsf{L} = \mathsf{NL}$, which is considered unlikely.

For references, see [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/39961/is-it-known-if-cfl-subseteq-nspaceolog2n) and [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/is-cfl-strictly-contained-in-nl) on cstheory.